# identify error origin in apache http server log

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging, httpserver

I have apache http 2.2 server load balance to several tomcat application servers running java servlets.  Sometimes there are error response coming back
in http log it shows:

```
212.xx.xx.x - - [09/Aug/2012:05:07:32 -0700] "GET /myservlet/myService?inputParam=xxx HTTP/1.1" 500 627
```

is there a way for me to log the tomcat ip or some kind of id so that I can identify which tomcat server is producing the error?

Comment: I like this question.  It's a shame there's not some sort of request ID that could be used to track the request through multiple servesr.  Can you simply look into the Tomcat logs for a matching timestamp?  Or are you getting hundreds of requests/second so that this is difficult?

Comment: ...although having said that, I would probably like this question more on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/), since it's not really programming related.

Comment: larsks: yes it's difficult to look at timestamps due to the high traffic